A proof in BCHM about the finite generation of the Cox ring
I was reading the paper Birkar, Cascini, Hacon, and McKernan - Existence of minimal models for varieties of log general type.
There is a consequence about a finite generation for Cox ring associated with a finite sequence of divisors as follows:

Corollary 1.1.9. Let $\pi: X \longrightarrow U$ be a projective morphism of normal quasi-projective varieties. Fix $A \geq 0$ an ample $\mathbb{Q}$-divisor over $U$. Let $\Delta_i=A+B_i$, for some $\mathbb{Q}$-divisors $B_1, B_2, \ldots, B_k \geq 0$.  (i.e. a sequence of big divisor $\Delta_i$)
Assume that $D_i=K_X+\Delta_i$ is DLT and $\mathbb{Q}$-Cartier (that is we construct a sequence of pairs $(X,\Delta_i)$).
Then the Cox ring $$ \mathfrak R\left(\pi, D^{\bullet}\right)=\bigoplus_{m \in \mathbb{N}^k} \pi_* \mathcal{O}_X\left(\left\llcorner\sum m_i D_i\right\lrcorner\right), $$
is a finitely generated $\mathcal{O}_U$-algebra.


For simplicity we assume $(X,\Delta)$ is log smooth where $\Delta = \Delta_1 + \dotsb + \Delta_i$.


The main idea of the proof is the following (which reduces a sequence of divisors into a single divisor):
Pick a positive integer $m$ such that $D_i=m\left(K_X+\Delta_i\right)$ is integral for $1 \leq i \leq k$. Let
$$
E=\bigoplus_{i=1}^k \mathcal{O}_X\left(m \Delta_i\right)
$$
and let $Y=\mathbb{P}_X(E)$ with projection map $f: Y \longrightarrow X$.

Pick $\sigma_i \in \mathcal{O}_X\left(m \Delta_i-m A\right)$ with zero locus $m \Delta_i$ and let $\sigma=\left(\sigma_1, \sigma_2, \dotsc, \sigma_k\right) \in H^0(X, E(-m A))$. Let $S$ be the divisor corresponding to $\sigma$ in $Y$.

Let $T_1, T_2, \dotsc, T_k$ be the divisors on $Y$, given by the summands of $E$, let $T$ be their sum, and

let $\Gamma=T+f^* A+S / m$.

Note that $\mathcal{O}_Y\left(m\left(K_Y+\Gamma\right)\right)$ is the tautological bundle associated to $E\left(m K_X\right)$ (indeed if $k=1$, this is clear and if $k>1$, then it has degree one on the fibres and $\mathcal{O}_Y\left(m\left(K_Y+\Gamma\right)\right)$ restricts to the tautological line bundle on each $T_i$ by adjunction and induction on $k$).

Thus
$$
\mathfrak{R}\left(\pi, D^{\bullet}\right) \simeq \mathfrak{R}\left(\pi \circ f, m\left(K_Y+\Gamma\right)\right) .
$$


We reduce the problem about the sequence of divisors into the problem with a single divisor.

Here is the question:
(Question 1) It's not clear why in (4) $\mathcal{O}_Y\left(m\left(K_Y+\Gamma\right)\right)$ is the tautological bundle associated with $E\left(m K_X\right)$, I have a hard time proving it.
(Question 2) Why can the tautological line bundle condition be used to reduce the problem into a single divisor problem
$$
\mathfrak{R}\left(\pi, D^{\bullet}\right) \simeq \mathfrak{R}\left(\pi \circ f, m\left(K_Y+\Gamma\right)\right)?
$$

I already solved Question 2, indeed the only thing we need is the direct image of the tautological line bundle is the symmetric product of the vector bundle $E$ (see e.g. Demailly's agbook (15.14) Theorem.)

The statement of Corollary 1.1.9 is that the ring is a finitely generated $\mathcal O_U$-algebra (although actually it says "algebras"). Is their statement a typo, or your transcription?

Thank you for pointing it out LSpice, it should be an algebra, as it has multiplication defined on the graded elements
